(When) Does GLMM provide better predictions than logistic regression?
I am trying to test statsmodels GLMM vs logistic regression (by either statsmodels or scikit-learn - see the code with a toy example below). I understand the utility of mixed models in parameter estimation, and that this model might be more truthful in terms of Akaike or some other criterion. However, I am not sure whether and when I should expect improvement in prediction accuracy, when testing on data coming from unknown groups.
Here is the code with a toy example:
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from scipy.special import expit

seed = 2024

"""
Comparing logistic regression with GLM
"""

#Generating mixed data
n_smpls = 1000
n_feats = 5
n_groups = 100

groups = np.repeat(np.arange(n_groups), n_smpls//n_groups)

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=2024)
X_train = np.random.normal(size=(n_smpls, n_feats))

offs = np.random.normal(size=n_groups, scale=0.5)
offsets = np.array([offs[g] for g in groups])

x0 = 0.; b = 10.
y_train = (np.random.random_sample(n_smpls) < expit(b * (X_train[:,0]-x0-offsets))).astype(np.float64) 

#Generating test data
m_smpls = 100
xmax = 1.
xx = np.linspace(-xmax, xmax, m_smpls)
X_test = np.random.normal(size=(m_smpls, n_feats))
X_test[:,0] = xx
prob_test = expit(b * (X_test[:,0] - x0))
y_test = (np.random.random_sample(m_smpls) < prob_test).astype(np.float64) 


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#scaling data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

preds = []
probs = [prob_test]
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#sklearn logistic regression
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=seed, penalty='l2')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
preds.append(y_pred)

prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
probs.append(prob)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Logistic regression by Statsmodels
clf = sm.GLM(y_train, X_train_scaled, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit_regularized(L1_wt=.9, alpha=.01)

prob = clf.predict(X_test_scaled)
probs.append(prob)

y_pred = (prob > 0.5).astype(float)
preds.append(y_pred)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#GLMM with statsmodels
Z_train = np.zeros((n_smpls, n_groups))
Z_train[np.arange(n_smpls), groups] = 1
glmm = sm.BinomialBayesMixedGLM(y_train, X_train_scaled, Z_train, np.arange(n_groups))
clf = glmm.fit_vb(scale_fe=True)

prob = clf.predict(X_test_scaled)
probs.append(prob)

y_pred = (prob > 0.5).astype(float)
preds.append(y_pred)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Analyzing results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 4))
for name, prob in zip(['test', 'lr', 'glm', 'glmm'], probs):
    ax.plot(xx, prob, label=name)
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel(r'$X_0$')
ax.set_ylabel('prob')
ax.set_title('Predicted probability')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

The resulting figure is:

We see here that in terms of predicting the probability GLMM does better, but it produces the same intercept, and no improvement in the classification accuracy: one could evaluate the numbers of true/false positive and the related metrics. E.g., for true positive/negative rates one gets
[np.sum((y_pred==1)&(y_test==1))/np.sum(y_test==1) for y_pred in preds]
[0.9782608695652174, 0.9782608695652174, 0.9565217391304348]

with the results
[0.9782608695652174, 0.9782608695652174, 0.9565217391304348]
[0.9074074074074074, 0.9259259259259259, 0.9259259259259259]


Since you are already working on probabilistic predictions, I would stick with those and not assess thresholded "hard" predictions.

@StephanKolassa I am working in a medical setting, where one has to make decisions healthy/sick.

@RogerV. that's no excuse. see https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ (which was in the answers linked in the previous comment): "A frequent argument from data users, e.g., physicians, is that ultimately they need to make a binary decision, so binary classification is needed. This is simply not true. First of all, it is often the case that the best decision is “no decision; get more data” when the probability of disease is in the middle. In many other cases, the decision is revocable, e.g., the physician starts the patient on a drug at a lower dose ..."

.... and even if you do need to threshold your predictions: you are starting with probabilistic ones, so it makes sense to separate this modeling step and assess it on its own merits, and only subsequently consider which threshold(s) are optimal. 0.5 is usually not the best answer.

@seanv507 This is a point of view valid for a researcher, even a medical researcher... but not in real medical setting: I am not sure how a medical doctor could prescribe a treatment with probability 12% or a cancer test with probability 70% - they either do it or not. What is more important for me: this binary logic underlies the FDA and other equivalent medical authorities requirements for medications, tests, etc.

@RogerV. Sure, the doctor either prescribes a treatment or not, but your regression does not.

@Dave the doctor follows protocols, developed via statistical studies - prescribing him/her binary decisions. I would need a more detailed example to judge, whether this talk of probability has more than academic value (no offense intended - I spent decades in academia , and I know that the gap between academia and real applications is large...)

@Dave the closest example I van think of is detection of trisomy: e.g., in France the first obligatory ultrasound exam is at 11 weeks (just below the legal abortion threshold) and one is provided with a probability that the foetus is trisomic... but there is a hard set threshold for this probability, above which it mandates actual genetic test, by taking a sample of amniotic liquid (an invasive and risky procedure.)

There is no good answer to this. to some extent L2 regularised logistic regression is a subset of a GLMM model.  As such you should be able to replicate any L2 regularised logistic regression by GLMM.
in your statsmodels code you are using elastic net regularisation, in sklearn code, you are using L2.
GLMM estimates the regularisation parameters from the training data, whereas in a typical ML application, you estimate the parameter using crossvalidation to maximise test prediction score.
Just as what value of the regularisation parameteer or whether L1 or L2 regularisation performs better depends on your data, so will whether using regularised glm or GLMM.

Actually, I am planning to use GPBoost - GLMM is just a warm-up. More precisely, I have already tried GPBoost on my real data... but I don't see any improvement (and a big disadvantage of being restricted to a specific ML algorithm.)
